# nvcc fatal : Could not open output file

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, nvcc

I use pytorch to object detection algorithms on windows:

When I run `ext/build.py build_ext develop` script
from https://github.com/lufficc/SSD repository
or when I run `python support/setup.py develop`
from https://github.com/potterhsu/easy-faster-rcnn.pytorch repository

```
import glob
import os

import torch
from setuptools import setup
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import CUDA_HOME
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import CppExtension
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import CUDAExtension

requirements = ["torch", "torchvision"]


def get_extensions():
    this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    extensions_dir = os.path.join(this_dir, "src")

    main_file = glob.glob(os.path.join(extensions_dir, "*.cpp"))
    source_cpu = glob.glob(os.path.join(extensions_dir, "cpu", "*.cpp"))
    source_cuda = glob.glob(os.path.join(extensions_dir, "cuda", "*.cu"))

    sources = main_file + source_cpu
    extension = CppExtension

    extra_compile_args = {"cxx": []}
    define_macros = []

    if torch.cuda.is_available() and CUDA_HOME is not None:
        extension = CUDAExtension
        sources += source_cuda
        define_macros += [("WITH_CUDA", None)]
        extra_compile_args["nvcc"] = [
            "-DCUDA_HAS_FP16=1",
            "-D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__",
            "-D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__",
            "-D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__",
        ]

    sources = [os.path.join(extensions_dir, s) for s in sources]

    include_dirs = [extensions_dir]

    ext_modules = [
        extension(
            "support._C",
            sources,
            include_dirs=include_dirs,
            define_macros=define_macros,
            extra_compile_args=extra_compile_args,
        )
    ]

    return ext_modules


setup(
    name="support",
    version="0.1",
    ext_modules=get_extensions(),
    cmdclass={"build_ext": torch.utils.cpp_extension.BuildExtension},
)
```

I get the same error:

> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin\nvcc.exe
>   -c C:\Users\along\PycharmProjects\SSD\ext\cuda\nms.cu -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Users\along\PycharmProjects\SSD\ext\cuda\nms.obj
>   -IC:\Users\along\PycharmProjects\SSD\ext -IC:\Users\along\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\include -IC:\Users\along\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\include\torch\csrc\api\include
>   -IC:\Users\along\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\include\TH -IC:\Users\along\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\include\THC "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\include"
>   -IC:\Users\along\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\along\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" -Xcompiler
>   /EHsc -Xcompiler /wd4819 -Xcompiler /MD -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__
>   -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr -DCUDA_HAS_FP16=1 -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=torch_extension -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -gencode=arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 nvcc fatal   : Could not open output file 'along\AppData\Local\Temp/tmpxft_00005b70_00000000' error:
>   command 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
>   Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin\nvcc.exe' failed with exit status 1

I don't know what is the error, I have a GPU device on the computer

I think that the problem is on CMakeLists.txt file on Anaconda3\pkgs\pytorch-1.3.1-py3.7_cuda92_cudnn7_0\info\test\test\custom_operator directory:

```
# Basic CMake setup
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project(custom_ops)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

add_library(custom_ops SHARED op.cpp)

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../third_party/pybind11/ ./pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(custom_class SHARED classes.cpp)
target_link_libraries(custom_class PRIVATE "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")

target_compile_features(custom_ops PUBLIC cxx_range_for)
target_link_libraries(custom_ops "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
target_compile_definitions(custom_ops PRIVATE custom_ops_EXPORTS)

add_executable(test_custom_ops test_custom_ops.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_custom_ops custom_ops)
```

Comment: `nvcc fatal : Could not open output file` means either your hard disk is full or you don't have write permissions where you are trying to build

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Is there an answer to be added?